# Is there a way that I can keep a user logged in throughout multiple forms after an initial login

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am fairly new to coding in C# and using windows forms applications and SQLite for databases, and I was wondering if there way that I can keep a user logged in and display said user's ID on different forms to show that they are logged in. The project itself is an ordering system and I wish for a customer to login to perform any purchases so that it can be logged as part of a management report. The code is below if it is of any help.

```
int charlengthusername= usernametextbox.Text.Length;
int charlengthpassword = passwordtextbox.Text.Length;
if (charlengthusername <= 4 || charlengthusername >= 6 || charlengthpassword >=13||String.IsNullOrEmpty(usernametextbox.Text)||String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordtextbox.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Details Entered Don't Meet The Expected Character Length Requirements. Try Again.");
    usernametextbox.Clear();
    passwordtextbox.Clear();
}
//make another if for user and pass matching  
//change else below to be inside of username and password match if statement so that it will only send to custmainmenu when username and password has been matched
else
{
    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=CustomerDatabase.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");
    sqlite_conn.Open();
    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
    string user = usernametextbox.Text;
    string pass = passwordtextbox.Text;
    sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_cmd.Connection = sqlite_conn;
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TblCustomer where CustRandID='" + usernametextbox.Text + "' AND CustPassword='" + passwordtextbox.Text + "'";
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (sqlite_datareader.Read())
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful! ");
        this.Hide();
        var openmainmenu = new CustomerMainMenu();
        openmainmenu.Closed += (t, args) => this.Close();
        openmainmenu.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrct Details! Try Again! ");
        this.Hide();
        var spenmainmenu = new CustomerLogin();
        spenmainmenu.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        spenmainmenu.Show();
    }
    sqlite_conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your app is vulnerable to SQL injection vulnerabilities (e.g. they could log in as any user by entering the password `' OR 1 AND '' = ` (or similar); look into using parametrized queries instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static members in a class and reach them from any form.

```
   class UserInfo {
        public static String UserName  ="";
        public static bool IsLoggedIn  = false;
    }
```

You need to set values inside of login successful block like that:

```
UserInfo.IsLoggedIn = true;
UserInfo.UserName = "Uday Patel";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to just store the validated username/password in a public static property in a static class.

```
public static class AppInfo {
  public static string Username = "";
}

// ...

MessageBox.Show("Login Successful! ");
AppInfo.Username = user;
```

You can then access that `Username` (and any other global data your app might need) from `AppInfo` (which you could name something else, of course).